# how to get a node by its position in the list in java? (not the value, the whole node)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have a linked list and a position of a node, and I need to get the node itself from the list (not only its value). Is there a func in java that does that? if not, can you send a piece of code that does that?

Thanks.

Comment: which list implementation are you using? where's the code? please show us in code what is it that you're trying to do otherwise it won't be easy to help you!

Comment: I dont have a code for that. Its part of a bigger project I'm working on. Thats why I asked the question. Otherwise I would have already added code to the question.

Comment: Also if you look at the tags, you can see a little "Linked-List" hiding in there

Comment: There's [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in Java APIs but you might use another implementation as well. Unless you're really specific with your question there's no way people can help you.

Comment: ok. i will edit it now

Comment: is that better?

Comment: is what better than what?

Comment: better than before

Comment: made it a little more specific

Comment: I don't see it...

Comment: idk what to change and anyway gotta go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Java’s `LinkedList` doesn’t allow you to work directly on the nodes.

If you need an O(1) “pointer”, you can use a ListIterator: `list.listIterator()`

If your linked list is a custom implementation, I’m 99% sure it’s your homework and you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int _data) {
        this.data = _data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (Integer.toString(data));
    }
}




public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList linkedlist = new LinkedList();

        linkedlist.InsertNode(15);
        linkedlist.InsertNode(20);
        linkedlist.InsertNode(25);
        linkedlist.InsertNode(30);
        linkedlist.InsertNode(35);
        linkedlist.showLinkedList();
        System.out.println("\n");
           Node retnode = linkedlist.retPosNode(2);
            System.out.println("REturn Node: "+retnode.data);
            linkedlist.showLinkedList();


    }

    Node head;

    public void InsertNode(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);

        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node n = head;
            while (n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = node;
        }
    }
    public Node retPosNode(int pos) {
    Node curr = head;
    Node prev= null;
    Node retPos= null;
    int i=0;
    if (curr==null)
    return null;

    while(curr!=null) {
        if(i==pos) {
            if(i!=0) {
            retPos = curr;
            prev.next= curr.next;
            curr = curr.next;
            }
            else {
                retPos = curr;
                head=  curr.next;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
        prev= curr;
        curr = curr.next;
        i++;
    }
    return retPos;

    }

    public void showLinkedList() {
        Node node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }   
}
```